# jQuery Repeater + Append on Select and Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery Repeater (https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater)  inside an invoice edit page that I'm creating. The repeater is used to repeat the items of an invoice (Item title, price and a select of taxes). We can, using an ajax form, add a new Tax. The new tax is added to the existant list of items, but once you click on Add item, it looks like repeater is using the first created set of options in the select, and not the last one containing the newly created option.

[image]

Here is the repeater code I'm using

```
$(".invoice-item-repeater").length && $(".invoice-item-repeater").repeater({
            show: function () {
                $(this).slideDown(function () {
                    $('.tax').trigger('change', true);
                })
            }, hide: function (e) {
                $(this).slideUp(e, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    calculate()
                });
            }
        });
```

All select taxes are with class .tax

As you may see in the example the 14% tax is added on the ajax form, and are added to the first two sets of selects options as they were already in the DOM when created the new tax, but for the next Added item, we have only 0% without the new 14% tax.

Comment: it's a selector problem i think,could you please check how many elements are triggered with ```.tax``` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should trigger each element.

```
$(this).slideDown(function () {
        $('.tax').each(function (_, el) {
            el.trigger('change', true);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It cant be as if it was an iteration problem othere wont be updated as well